# need group by data in mysql

Tags: mysql, logic

in mysql:

Have data in data:

```
ColA | ColB | Rank
1      2      0
1      3      1
2      1      0
3      1      0
3      2      1
```

Keeping Col A as key field, need to get data on base of highest rank i.e.,
output:

```
ColA | ColB | Rank
1      3      1
2      1      0
3      2      1
```

any ideas..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
SELECT T1.ColA, T2.ColB, T1.Rank
FROM TableName T2 JOIN
(SELECT ColA,MAX(Rank) as Rank
FROM TableName 
GROUP BY ColA) T1 ON T1.ColA=T2.ColA AND T1.Rank=T2.Rank
```

**Explanation:**

1. Inner query (T1) selects records with highest rank for each values of `ColA`.
2. Outer query (T2) is used to select `ColB` with respect to the values of `ColA` and Rank from T2.

**Result:**

```
ColA    ColB    Rank
--------------------
1       3       1
2       1       0
3       2       1
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/242f0/7)